# When to use “Bedürfnis” and “Bedarf”?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *Bedürfnis* and *Bedarf* when meaning *the need?*
I am confused when I want to say *the need;* I dont know which to use.

Comment: What did the dictionary say?

Comment: @Robert: most translations give, among some others, "requirement" or "need" for both, which is not very helpful, IMO.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That's when you look at the translations that don't overlap.

Comment: @Robert how could I differentiate between words of Same meaning in your opinion!!

Comment: @Robert: Most of them do overlap. As I said: not very useful.

Comment: Hello Hussien, did you have a look at the comments below underneath the various answers. If you did you will have understood that the question of *Bedarf* vs. *Bedürfnisse* is one that has the potential to devide the German speaking world (including neighbouring idioms such as Dutch) and is largely unsettled (at least in the finer traits).

Answer (score 30):

I'd say that *Bedürfnis* is more a personal need or desire or even urge, while *Bedarf* is an objective necessity or demand:

> Ich habe das Bedürfnis, ganz nah an der Stadt zu wohnen.
> I have the desire to live close to the city.
>
> Der Bedarf an neuen Glühbirnen war schwer zu decken.
> The demand for new lightbulbs was hard to fulfill.

But both come from "bedürfen", AFAIK.

Comment: Very well explained, in just two lines!

Comment: @Christian: dankjewel!

Comment: Weder ist `personal need or desire` (Beispiel: Schlafbedürfnis) notwendig subjektiv, noch ist Bedarf immer objektiv (Beispiel: Ausbau der Stadtautobahn).

Comment: Ich würde sagen: wenn jemand (objektiv) zu wenig Schlaf bekommt, dann gibt es einen Schlafbedarf. Wenn jemand nur gern schläft, dann ist das eher ein Bedürfnis. Und m.E. gilt: wenn die Stadtautobahn wirklich ausgebaut werden muss, dann ist das ein Bedarf. Wenn nicht, dann ist das eher ein Bedürfnis der Politiker oder der Autofahrer. Und wahrscheinlich gibt es, wie fast von jeder Regel, Ausnahmen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Nein. Ich habe ein Schlafbedürfnis wenn ich müde bin, und Müdigkeit ist ein objektiver Zustand, auch wenn ich jetzt in diesem Zustand bin, meine Frau aber nicht. Er kann also objektiv vorliegen (mehrere Wissenschaftler können anhand klarer Kriterien mit Messmethoden messen, ob das wahr ist und unabhängig voneinander zum gl. Ergebnis gelangen und bei wiederholten Messungen immer wieder zum gl. Ergebnis kommen). Der Bedarf ist dann soundsoviel Stunden Schlaf, also die Menge an etwas, das das Bedürfnis befriedigt.

Comment: … Oberflächlich wird gerne alles, was mit Gefühlen verbunden ist, als subjektiv betrachtet, so als hätte es >100 Jahre Psychologie und >100 Jahre Biologie und Medizin usw. nicht gegeben, als wären Gefühle Einbildung. Dem einen ist kalt, dem anderen nicht, also subjektiv, also nicht messbar? Nein, die Menschen sind unterschiedlich (Fettschicht, Empfindsamkeit) und während sich beim einen die Hährchen schon aufrichten und eine Gänsehaut bildet, weil ihm objektiv kalt ist, ist dem anderen noch nicht kalt - objektiv messbar, geringe Reaktionsbildung.

Comment: @user: Gefühle sind keine *Einbildung*, aber sehr wohl *subjektiv*. Und wie Leute Kälte empfinden hängt nicht nur von korperlichen Dingen ab, sondern ist teilweise auch emotional bedingt. Objektiv kann man nur die Temperatur messen, und wenn notwendig, auch die innerkörperliche, und die Reaktion darauf. Mit anderen Worten, man kann objektiv die Reaktionen des Körpers messen, ausgelöst vom subjektiven Empfinden. Aber Gefühle sind und bleiben subjektiv.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Nein, Du vermengst die unterschiedlichen Bedeutungsebenen, auf denen Subjektivität und Objektivität gleichzeitig vorliegen können. Ob es in einem Raum kalt ist, ist insofern subjektiv, als unterschiedliche Leute im gleichen Raum, auch unterstellt sie sind ehrlich, zu unterschiedlichen Ergebnissen können können. Ob dem Einzelnen aber kalt ist oder nicht, das kann - zumindest theoretisch - objektiv geklärt werden, weil es mit Symptomen einhergeht.

Comment: Für die Beantwortung der Frage hilft eine eingebrachte Unterscheidung von personal gegen Bedarf nicht weiter. Ein Junkie kann gegenüber einem Mitjunkie sagen, sein Tagesbedarf an Heroin sei 1g. Dass Heroin objektiv schädlich ist, und sein wahrer Bedarf 0g wäre, oder dass der Mitjunkie schon 2g täglich braucht oder nur ein halbes ändert an der Angemessenheit des Begriffs "Bedarf" gar nichts. Und auch nichts am Bedürfnis. Er hat ein Rauschbedürfnis, welches er mit dem Bedarf zu befriedigen hofft.

Comment: @user: Er empfindet es als objektiven Bedarf, und sagt es deswegen auch so. Was Leute sagen, muss nicht immer korrekt sein. Was Leute als objektiv empfinden muss es nicht immer sein. Aber bedenke: wenn er abhängig ist, dann ist das wahrscheinlich wirklich was er braucht, um über den Tag zu kommen.

Comment: Das Problem ist, dass Du mit den Attributen 'objektiv' und 'persönlich' die Begriffe zu erklären versuchst. Jetzt musst Du aber selbst zwischen objektivem und subjektivem Bedarf unterscheiden. Daraus folgt, dass die Objektivität eben nicht in den Begriff eingeschrieben ist, also nicht als Unterscheidungskriterium taugt.  Schade für Dich, hast Du doch viele damit überzeugen können. Das ist aber GL-Rhetorik, nicht gutes Antworten, wie es sein sollte.

Comment: @user: das wird mir zu philosophisch. Ich finde, das ein Bedarf normalerweise objektiv is und ein Bedürfnis subjektiv. Es gibt m.E. keinen subjektiven Bedarf, höchstens das subjektive Empfinden, dass etwas ein Bedarf sei. Kommt vor. Du trennst "objektiv" und "subjektiv" anscheinend anders als ich. Das tut mir leid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72996/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-rudy-velthuis).

Comment: @user: no. I don't discuss in chat. I like to see my replies under the answer or question, not somewhere neatly tucked away in a chat no one will see.

Comment: Das Bedürfnis nah der Stadt zu wohnen geht also mit einem Bedarf an einer stadtnahen Wohnung einher. Der Bedarf an Glühbirnen ist ausgelöst von einem Bedürfnis besser sehen zu können.

Comment: @user: Es ist gut. Genug. Wir kommen hier nicht zusammen.

Comment: Ist Dein Bedarf gedeckt, das Bedürfnis nach weiterer Diskussion erloschen?

Answer (score 4):

Side note, but worth knowing:

Especially when speaking to bureaucrats and social workers and the like in Germany (I don't know about other regions with German lingua prima) you will frequently hear or read

> *Bedarfe [odd!]

as a plural form of *Bedarf*. This is so frequent (in that environment) that its occurrence in the working documents and communication of respective institutions is probably outweighing the use of actual *Bedarf*.

This use has become popular in those sectors of the world of work over, I would say the past 5-10 years (my personal observation, I have not done representative statistical research into it).

However, professional writers (newspaper editors, copywriters, book editors, etc.) despise this as an abomination. Originally and traditionally, and still today in good style, *Bedarf* does not have a plural form. It is simply one *Bedarf* (for what ever; may well be the *Bedarf* of multiple people for multipe things, and still one *Bedarf*), similar to *Milch* and *Schnee* which is always one and never multiple "Milche" or "Schneee".

---

**Afterthoughts**

**A note on how occurrence of *Bedarf* and *Bedarfe* is reported in Ngram** (as @tofro mentioned this in the comments): notably Ngram shows a very low rate of *Bedarfe* as compared to *Bedarf* for German documents, with an interesting peak, however, in 1880-1900. The latter is, I would suppose, most probably for *Bedarfe* as the old-school dative form of (singular) *Bedarf* --> *dem Bedarfe*. Regarding the very low count of *Bedarfe* in general: supposed that Google Ngram uses a more or less representative selection of documents (and this back into the reported decades [which I doubt until proof of the opposite]), still this would reflect frequencies in overall language. My observation about the inflationary use of plural *Bedarfe* relates, however, to specific vocational (and bureaucratic) environments.

Comment: Um's mit Obelix zu sagen: "Die spinnen, die deutschen Bürokraten!". Aber was ist ODD? "Optical Disk Drive"? Oder nur "odd"?

Comment: No. I cannot find any trace whatsoever that "Bedarf" is (or ever was) singular only. Care to have a look at ngrams? That's just wrong.

Comment: @tofro: Officially, it may not be the case, but "Bedarfe" sounds extremely weird to me too. And well, ngrams only reflect what people use, not if they are correct. And it seems there is a huge discrepancy between "Bedarf" and "Bedarfe". Probably the few books using "Bedarfe" were written by bureaucrats. <g>

Comment: @tofro: Duden says that "Bedarfe" is "Fachsprache". That makes sense. To me, "Bedarf" is just as singular as, say, "Hunger" or "Durst".

Comment: Die stärksten Kritiker der Milche waren früher selber Knilche.

Comment: While this tangentially adresses the question of what to use for *the need,* this is very obfuscated. Can you edit your answer to address this?

Comment: *similar to* Milch *which is always one and never multiple "Milche".* – Kuhmilch, Schafsmilch, Ziegenmich und Büffelmilch sind verschiedene Milche.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich würde sagen: Kuhmilch, Schafsmilch, usw. sind verschiedene Milchsorten, und nicht verschiedene "Milche". Duden nennt "Milche" auch Fachsprache, wie "Bedarfe". <g>

Comment: @tofro  Yes of course would you find plenty of "Bedarfe" with Ngram; as you know they just scan a lot of existing documents (books, papers, whatsoever). This is what I said in my answer: it spreads like a viral infection. Nevertheless it is a disease. - It may have become common in certain vocations, but it is still not suitable for general publishing.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann You didn't care to look, apparently. Your answer says "it's a modern disease that came up during the last 10 years." ngrams says the opposite.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  I would say *ODD* is an odd way of spelling *odd*. (Changed it, to please your eye.)

Comment: @Christian: ah, yes, right. Got it.

Comment: @tofro  Thanks for the hint. After looking at the Ngram graphs for *Bedarf* and *Bedarfe* in German I come to a different conclusion than you. See the added note in my answer above.

Comment: Now you (again) drew a (wrong) conclusion before looking in the books ngrams actually found.

Comment: @tofro  Hm. Now for the fun of it I selected one book of the 1880s period from Google's citations there and looked up what they have there as "Bedarfe". And what? It is a misread "Bedarfs" (genitive), as Google does not read the old letter faces well. - I will not further look into the individual books and keep my claim that *Bedarfe* as a plural word has become a fashion in some vocations etc. in recent years. But I will read a more thorrough analysis of yours with pleasure.

Comment: @tofro  PS: If you set the Ngram period to "until 2008" (that's obviously the maximum possible currently), you see for "Bedarfe" a clearly growing frequency starting around the year 2000.

Answer (score 4):

"Bedarf" - a need in the sense of something that is required or necessary. This is typically a physical thing or an activity. A "Bedarf" is something that can be acquired.

"Bedürfnis" - a need in the sense of a personal desire or want. Rarely a physical thing, typically an activity or an emotional thing. A "Bedürfnis" is something that can be satisfied.

"Ich habe Bedarf an ..." - I need ...

"Ich habe das Bedürfnis nach ..." - I want to ...

Answer (score 2):

*Bedarf* hat man an etwas, das ein *Bedürfnis* befriedigt.

- Mein Bedarf an Marzipanbroten ist noch lange nicht gedeckt.
- Familie X hat einen monatlichen Bedarf an Lebensmitteln im Wert von Y Euro.
- Mein Schlafbedürnis war so stark, dass ich aufs Zähneputzen verzichtete.
- Das Liebesbedürfnis der jungen Teens ist quasi unstillbar.

Im Gegensatz zu einem Tier kann eine Maschine zwar einen Bedarf haben (Platzbedarf, Energie, Rohstoffe, ...) aber keine Bedürfnisse. Bei Pflanzen, etwa dem Wurzelwerk eines Baumes, spricht man auch von einem Bedarf, aber eigentlich nicht von Bedürfnissen. Letzteres würde ich aber für diskutierbar halten und es würde mich im Jargon professioneller Gruppen auch nicht sehr überraschen, wenn doch, immerhin kann man metaphorisch auch unbelebten Dingen Bedürfnisse zuordnen, etwa "Die Lawine hat das Bedürfnis abzugehen" und so kann auch eine Pilzkultur das Bedürfnis zeigen, sich auszudehnen.

Hunger ist ein Grundbedürfnis. Wäre er nicht messbar, würden wir uns ständig zu große oder zu kleine Portionen Essen aufladen. Wer sich Marzipanbrote kauft, um damit seinen Hunger zu stillen, der hat vielleicht seinen Bedarf gedeckt, aber solange er noch nicht angefangen hat zu essen, ist das Bedürfnis unverändert. Bedürfnis und Bedarf sind also kategorial unterschiedlich.

Comment: Dieser "Bedarf" an Marzipanbrot ist kein echter Bedarf, es gibt nur das subjektive (und ausgesprochene) Empfinden, dass es ein Bedarf sei.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Ein Bedürfnis nach Revanche spricht aus Deiner Antwort, und ich schätze es ist Dein echtes Bedürfnis. Was mein echter Bedarf ist und was nicht, das lass mal meine Sorge sein - Du bist nicht die obere Marzipanzuteilungsbehörde, die die Kompetenz hätte, über meinen Marzipanbedarf Spekulationen anzustellen. Du kannst zwar einen Kontext erfinden, in dem mein Bedarf nur ein Hirngespinst ist, aber ich kann ebensogut einen Kontext erfinden, in dem er das nicht ist. In beiden Kontexten kann man aber von Bedarf sprechen und tut das auch.

Comment: "Ein Bedürfnis nach Revanche spricht aus Deiner Antwort". Nein, tut es nicht. Ich bin nur nicht deiner Meinung. Das kann passieren.

Comment: Dann nenne Argumente dafür oder dagegen. Rationalere Beispiele als Marzipan habe ich ja gebracht, Ruhebedürfnis, Kalorienbedarf, Vitaminbedarf, Platzbedarf einer Pflanze, ... - immer geht Bedarf mit Bedürfnissen einher und Bedürfnisse lösen einen Bedarf aus. Mit objektiv oder subjektiv hat das nichts zu tun, das ist ein Holzweg.

Comment: Ihr habt beide recht. Das bei manchen Personen regelmäßig oder sporadisch auftretende persönliche, gefühlte *Bedürfnis*, Marzipan zu essen, führt in der marktökonomischen, in Zahlen messbaren Folge zu einem Anstieg des *Bedarfs* an Marzipan.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Was ist mit dem Bedürfnis zu atmen, oder überhaupt zu essen - sind das auch nur gefühlte Bedürfnisse, feierlich als persönliche geadelt? Sind vitale Grundbedürfnisse nur eine beliebige Konvention? Ist die Maslowsche Bedürfnispyramide https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslowsche_Bed%C3%BCrfnishierarchie#1._Physiologische_Bed%C3%BCrfnisse Quatsch?

Comment: Very good first sentence! That actually completely answers the OP's question. Btw: I would, if I may intervene, suggest that "mein Bedarf an Marzipanbroten" contains an ironic element: As if there was an objective, measurable requirement where there is actually just a desire. Like "Kaffebedarf" for a programmer invokes the image of gasoline demand of a machine. So both @RudyVelthuis and you  have a point: Most likely there is no mandatory "Bedarf" (as could be proven experimentally), but we cannot know, and it sure feels like it.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Thanks. I would not dispute, that the usage of Marzipan is ironic, but this is orthogonal to the question of objectivity. Hunger is primarily a question of enough calories, and Marzipan has a very high dense of calories, that's not disputable. Every food can be substituted by another kind of food, but each could be used, to express the  amount - be it 500g bread or 100g marzipan bread, none of which is more objective than the other.There are only such, which are more conventional.

Answer (score 2):

One (if not the main) difference is that »Bedürfnis« refers to creatures wheras »Bedarf« is used universally.

> Auch Tiere haben Bedürfnisse.
>   *(Even animals have needs.)*
>
> Die Familie hat einen Platzbedarf von 80 Quadratmetern.
>   *(The family has a footprint of 80 square meters.)*
>
> Meine Baufirma hat einen wöchentlichen Betonbedarf von über 15 Tonnen.
>   *(My construction company has a weekly concrete requirement of over 15 tons.)*
>
> Prostituierte: »Brauchst du Sex?« *(Prostitute: »Do you need sex?«*
>   Pfarrer: »Kein Bedarf.« *(Pastor: »No need.«)*

Comment: Der Pfarrer ist also nach dieser Logik keine Kreatur?

Comment: @userunknown It seems *Bedürfnis* refers to personal desire, emotion, etc. whereas *Bedarf* is technical, factual, non-personal. Hence the priest on purpose choses *Bedarf* in order to not even give room to the thought that he could have personal *Bedürfnisse* (desire!) related to sex.

Comment: @userunknown: Meine Aussage ist, dass sich _»Bedürfnis«_ auf Lebewesen bezieht, _»Bedarf«_ kann sich auch auf anderes beziehen. Einen Pfarrer, ja, wahrhaftig, selbst ich zähle einen Pfarrer zu den Kreaturen.

Comment: Gut. 2. Frage: Für Lebewesen, kann man da die Wörter Bedürfnis und Bedarf wahlweise benutzen, austauschen? Was ist mit der Familie als Struktur von Lebewesen - kann eine Familie Bedürfnisse haben?

Comment: Ich würde sagen: *Bedürfnisse* sind tendenziell eher gefühlt und schwer messbar, *Bedarf* ist tendenziell eher unpersönlich und messbar. Insofern kann eine Familie sowohl Bedürfnisse als auch Formen von Bedarf (im Pädagogendeutsch: Bedarfe) haben. Es kommt halt auf den  Kontext an.

Comment: @userunknown: Wahlweise, nein. Ein Lieferant würde bei seinen Kunden eher von Bedarf sprechen. _»Welchen Bedarf hat der Kunde?«_ Und natürlich, so wie Menschen Bedürfnisse haben, so haben es auch Familien, da sie ja, wie bekannt sein dürfte, aus Menschen bestehen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "Bedürfnisse sind eher gefühlt" - sind oder werden? Soll das heißen, dass sie wie gefühlte Temperaturen, Einbildung sind? Was heißt schwer messbar? Du weißt vorm Einschlafen nicht, wie lange Du schlafen wirst oder vor'm Essen, wieviele Würste Dich sattmachen werden? Kleiner Trick - übersetz die Bedürfnisse in einen Bedarf, dann geht es plötzlich ganz leicht - it's magic!

Comment: @Pollitzer: Und Menschen bestehen aus Organen - hat die Zunge, der Magen einen Bedarf oder ein Bedürfnis? Die Haut? Das Gehirn? Sei's drum. Angenommen K. hat sehr viel Hunger, bekannt aus Film und Fernsehen als ein Grundbedürfnis und einen Bedarf an 500g Brot. K. kauft nun 1000g Brot, aber isst nicht sofort davon. Dann hat K. noch immer sein Bedürfnis, aber der Brotbedarf ist gedeckt. Das ist der Unterschied - nicht Messbarkeit oder Objektivität. Und Clara hat einen Strombedarf, aber kein Strombedürfnis. Es sind unterschiedliche Kategorien.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn Kalorien für einen Hungrigen gekauft, von ihm aber noch nicht gegessen sind, hat sein Körper nach wie vor einen Kalorienbedarf bzw. ein Essbedürfnis, hier funktionieren beide Begriffe.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Sicher, wenn man das Subjekt ändert, von der Person P zum Körper Ps und das Objekt, vom Marzipan zu den Kalorien des Marzipans. Ich schreibe  aber, dass die Person P Hunger hat und einen Marzipanbedarf (Person P als autonomes Subjekt vorgestellt, das selbständig entscheidet, wie es sich ernährt). Sie besorgt sich Marzipan und hat jetzt keinen Marzipanbedarf mehr sondern nur noch Hunger. Beleg: Würde sie weiteres Marzipan kaufen hätte sie immer noch Hunger, obwohl dann noch mehr Marzipan da wäre. Sie hat aber kaum einen unendlichen Marzipanbedarf.

Comment: @Mein letzter Kommentar: Hat Trixi Hunger auf Marzipan, finde ich es nicht falsch, zu sagen _»Trixi hat Marzipanbedarf«_. Die Begriffe _»Bedarf«_ und _»Bedürfnis«_ sind meines Erachtens nicht so scharf getrennt, wie du es gern hättest.